# Online exclusive product page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, blocks, static-block

I created this file (code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Exclusives.php) to get all product from the attribute 'online_exclusive' that is also part for a specific attribute set id.

The code works, but in (template\catalog\product\exclusives.phtml) the toolbar is returning empty.
If I remove `->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', $setID)` the toolbar returns a true value. I can't think of any other way to work this out. How else could I look for the attribute_set_id. This is being used as a sub category page that is displaying a static block.

`{{block type="catalog/product_exclusives" name="online.exclusives" alias="online.exclusives" column_count="6" products_count="400" template="catalog/product/exclusives.phtml"}}`

```
<?php

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Exclusives extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List{

   protected function _getProductCollection($setID){    
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
      $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

      $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
         ->addStoreFilter()
         ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', $setID)
         ->addAttributeToFilter('online_exclusive', true);

      $this->setProductCollection($collection);


      return $collection;
   }
   public function getLoadedProductOnlineExclusiveCollection($e){
     return $this->_getProductCollection($e);
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code from your `exclusives.phtml` file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this. I rewrote the function and extended _beforeToHtml()

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();

            $origCategory = null;

                $this->_productCollection  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId())
                        ->getProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('online_exclusive', true)
                        ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
                        ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
```